# Uploading files/images without "move_uploaded_files" (PHP)

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm handling file image uploads, as briefly described in the code below (just pieces taken out of whole code)

```
//get the temporary name of the uploaded file
$tmpName=$imgFile['tmp_name'];

if( !empty( $tmpName ) && is_uploaded_file( $tmpName ) ) { 
        //read the image from temporary uploaded data
        $im = @ImageCreateFromJpeg($tmpName);
        // resize the image
        $im=resize_photo($im);
        // create new image path and filename...
        // ...
        // store the image
        ImageJpeg($im, $photodir.$ds.$newname,50);
        }
// remove the temporary file ???
unlink($tmpName);
```

Script works fine, just temporary file is removed, but im not sure if the whole process is right. Can/Shall I remove the temporary file ? Can such Image upload work safely without using "move_uploaded_file" ? if not removed, are the temporary data deleted ?

Comment: and why not use `move_upload_file`?

Comment: You can create your own "tmp" folder, and delete old images using http://php.net/filemtime and http://php.net/unlink so maybe you could delete the photos with over 1 hour (or 1 day, etc).

Comment: It seems as though you are trying to re-invent the wheel. `move_uploaded_file` makes a new file from the temp file and then once your process is complete, the temp files are erased

Comment: I need to resample the image. So I need to open it anyhow and store in required size/quality. Moving the file means for me unnecessary step as well as making some temporary store folder.

Comment: @John simply move the file to the `$photodir.$ds.$newname`, so when you run `imagejpg()` it will overwrite. If a failure occurs, use `unlink();`

Comment: @Guilherme, I understand, but it is still one more step and actually will there be any difference ? The question is not how to use move_uploaded_file, but what can happen if I won't use it?

Comment: @John That I did not understand, why not use it?

Comment: @Guilherme, :))) that's the point of the question: why yes ? I haven't heard a single reason to use it in the case described, except that it is "standard way". Using the function doesn't bring any advantage, at least I cannot see it. On the other hand you can upload with this function non image file (with jpg extension).

Comment: @John This 'standard' is not logical. You can use either `copy();` and `move_upload();` the difference is that it is already a file on the server, even if the */tmp* folder.
I think you're a little confused, or you are trying to achieve something that you have not said (or could not explain).

Comment: I know it is on the server as temporary file. I am reading it. i don't need to copy or move it. The script works well. You keep telling me to use the function, but not a single reason why. Maybe the script is not secure, not stable, but i don't want to blindly add the function without knowing the **reason** and understanding possible threats. Please without a real reason do not tell me I shall use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are storing the data with `imagejpeg()` and therefore you are creating a new file, there is nothing temporarily about it.

The real temporary file (`$tmpname`) is temporary and will be removed by PHP when your http request ends.

Comment: @Guilherme, please do not add *random* formatting to *words* that you think are *important*.  It makes things hard to read.

Comment: @Charles Is a point of view.

Comment: @Guilherme, no, it's not a point of view.  [Formatting-only edits aren't encouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179951/135887).